# my 5v and 3.3v pins are not supplying current

Tags: gpio

Previously the 5V and 3.3V supply used to work, when i connected my gear motor it worked at first and the next day, i tried connecting 4 gear motors to a single driver ,powered by 8 double a batteries, it didn't work and now the 5v supply itself is not supplying any current. any suggestions??

Comment: Time to get a new Pi. Sounds like you killed this one.

Answer (score 4):

8 AA batteries in series will produce about 12 volts.

Given that your Pi appears to be damaged beyond recovery I'd guess you have fed that 12 volts into the Pi (via the 5V, 3V3 rails, or via a GPIO).

I suggest you post a schematic of your proposed wiring before you connect it to your new Pi.

Answer (score 1):

The 5V power pins supply WHATEVER you put in (some older Pi models have a polyfuse).

If the 5V does not work your PSU is dead.

Comment: is there any possible way to fix it?

Comment: @coder: No - there is no practical way to fix it. The organization that makes the Raspberry Pi does not even supply a full schematic of the board. You are now the owner of a [paperweight.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/paperweight)